# when particular date is selected in datepicker, how do i populate the particular day of week automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to show the particular day of week when the user select a particular date from datepicker.
When the user clicks on day button i want to automatically select the day of week for that selected date??

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:NO];
```

try this, let me know if it doesnt work. i havent tried it. 
hope it works, happy coding :)

Comment: not working... i want to automatically select the day in a week when the user select the date